# Convert string to array in Perl

Tags: perl

I want to convert a string into an array. I have something like this:

```
my $binvalue = 10101010101010101010101010101010;
```

And, I want to have that in an array...

```
my @array = (1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0)
```

And I want to do that to be able to index any value and change it.
Like if the most significant bit is 1, change it to 0.

Comment: Have you tried to use `split`?

Comment: Have you tried to use `unpack`?

Answer (score 3):

Try this. Note the "0b" to store the binary number.

```
my $binvalue = 0b10101010101010101010101010101010;
print "\$binvalue as decimal: $binvalue\n";

my @binvalues = split //, sprintf '%b', $binvalue;
print "\@binvalues: @binvalues\n";
```

Answer (score 2):

From the [split perldoc](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html):

> However, this:
>
> ```
> print join(':', split('', 'abc')), "\n";
> ```
>
> uses empty string matches as separators to produce the output 'a:b:c';
>   thus, the empty string may be used to split EXPR into a list of its
>   component characters.

Answer (score 2):

According to the split perldoc (see kjprice's answer) what you want should be something like

```
my @array = split('', $binvalue, x)
```

where x is the length of $binvalue, so:

```
my @array = split('', $binvalue, length($binvalue))
```

Comment: I think the OP is saying that `$binvalue` is a number which has the binary representation `10101010101010101010101010101010`, not a string of one's and zero's. In that case, `split` won't work. `unpack` is required: http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/unpack.html

Comment: @shawnhcorey It's a little misleading, but the question does say string.

Comment: Agreed but the OP did not use quotes around the string. So, I thought I should add how to do it for binary numbers, just in case. ;)